# Linkedin login with js

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

I am trying to implement login with linked in my web app. Here is my code..

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key: 'key here'
    </script>

</head>
<body>
   <script>
        IN.User.authorize(function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }, function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
   </script>
</body>
```

But its giving me error 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at Object.authorize (in.js:18)'

i have also tried this way..

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key:   'key here'
        onLoad:    'onLinkedInLoad'
        authorize: true
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- LinkedIn signin button -->
    <script type="in/Login"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
        function onLinkedInLoad() {
            IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

but its giving me errror

'in.js:7 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Could not instantiate tag for 'login': Cannot read property 'on' of null
    at new  (Login.js?version=0.1.149:7)
    at in.js:18'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428157/how-to-login-with-linkedin-using-javascript-and-display-profile-information

Answer (score 0):

The documentation and examples for linkedIn show api_key and onLoad function not being set as a string delimeter.

```js
api_key:   0192afsdj10
onLoad:    onLinkedInLoad
```

Secondly, you have not added in a function for the getProfileData function.

Here is an example of the should look like.

```js
function getProfileData() {
    IN.API.Profile("me").fields("id", "first-name", "last-name", "headline", "location", "picture-url", "public-profile-url", "email-address").result(displayProfileData);
}

function displayProfileData(profiles){
  var member = profiles.values[0];
  console.log(member);
}
```

See code referenced [here](https://www.codexworld.com/login-with-linkedin-using-javascript-sdk/)

Comment: I have seen your example and but the demo is not working and showing same error which is asked in this question